# AADSTS70011: The provided value for the input parameter 'scope' is not valid

Tags: c#, microsoft-graph-api

So I have a scenario wherein the application should add users to a group on certain conditions. Also when the application starts running users should not be asked to login their microsoft id/pwd.

So I access the token I created using Graph Service Client object as follows:

```cs
    GraphServiceClient graphClient = new GraphServiceClient(
        "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0", 
        new DelegateAuthenticationProvider(
            async (requestMessage) =>
            {
                string clientId = "My APP ID";
                string authorityFormat = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/{0}/v2.0";
                string tenantId = "tenant GUID";
                string[] _scopes = new string[] { 
                    "https://graph.microsoft.com/User.ReadBasic.All" 
                };
                // Custom Redirect URI asigned in the Application Registration 
                // Portal in the native Application Platform
                string redirectUri = "https://localhost:4803/"; 
                string clientSecret = "App Secret";
                ConfidentialClientApplication daemonClient = new ConfidentialClientApplication(
                    clientId, 
                    String.Format(authorityFormat, tenantId), 
                    redirectUri, 
                    new ClientCredential(clientSecret), 
                    null, new TokenCache()
                );
                AuthenticationResult authResult = await daemonClient.AcquireTokenForClientAsync(_scopes);
                string token = authResult.AccessToken;
                requestMessage.Headers.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("bearer", token);
            }
       )
    );
```

So I try to execute
`var user = await graphClient.Me.Request().GetAsync();`

I get this error:

> AADSTS70011: The provided value for the input parameter 'scope' is not valid. The scope user.read is not valid.

I also tried using just `User.ReadBasic` as scope, but get the same error.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Are you sure the scope should be `User.ReadBasic.All` and not `User.Read.All`? Make sure you use the right [permission](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/concepts/permissions_reference)

Comment: I tried User.Read.All and it gave me this error :AADSTS70011: The provided value for the input parameter 'scope' is not valid. The scope https://graph.microsoft.com/User.Read.All is not valid.

Comment: Because `graph.microsoft.com/User.Read.All` is in fact invalid. You should use `User.Read.All`

Comment: Tried with just "User.Read", but hardluck. Can you have a look at the code how grapserviceclient object is formed. Is there something wrong with object creation?

Comment: IMHO everything looks fine but I'm not expert in this field. Try checking out [examples on gihutb](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/aspnet-connect-rest-sample/blob/master/Microsoft%20Graph%20REST%20ASPNET%20Connect/Microsoft%20Graph%20REST%20ASPNET%20Connect/Helpers/SampleAuthProvider.cs)

Answer (score 127):

You are using the client credential flow here, which means that you cannot dynamically request scopes. You must configure your required permission scopes on your app registration in apps.dev.microsoft.com, then you set the value of scope in your code to `https://graph.microsoft.com/.default`.

See https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/concepts/auth_v2_service for more details.

Comment: If you're using a different API, replace everything before `.default` with its scheme and GUID: `api://11111111-2222-3333-4444-555555555555/.default`

Comment: ok, that's pretty obscure. Thank you Eric.  Have you got a source for that information?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/auth-v2-service#token-request

Comment: The answer provided to this question is the most robust i've seen [Scope Used for Authenticating to use an App Registration API - Microsoft Q&A](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/750966/scope-used-for-authenticating-to-use-an-app-regist)

Answer (score 4):

I recommend to use the [`.default` scope](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/scopes-oidc#the-default-scope)

> The `.default` scope is used to refer generically to a resource service (API) in a request, without identifying specific permissions...

> Clients can't combine static (`.default`) consent and dynamic consent in a single request. So `scope=https://graph.microsoft.com/.default Mail.Read` results in an error because it combines scope types.

To set your Scope var in C#:

```cs
string[] scope = new string[] {".default"};
```

To set your Scope var in Java:

```java
private final List<String> scope = Arrays.asList(".default");
```

Answer (score 0):

I had copied code from another authorize that was working for a user not an organization.
So I received the error because I had the wrong grant_type.

Make sure yours is "client_credentials"