# AADSTS7000014: The provided value for the input parameter 'device_code' is not valid Microsoft Graph

Tags: node.js, azure, azure-ad-msal

I want to get the microsoft user token using the msal-node nodejs module.
I don't know why i receive this error so if someone have a little idea ;-;:
[Error code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ry4BW.png)

I tried to retrieve the user microsoft token by using the acquireTokenByDeviceCode msal's function. [code sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BfJT4.png)

The PublicClientApplication object contain clientId (from the azureAD panel) and authority (https://login.microsoftonline.com/consumers) informations.

Thanks in advance ^^

Answer (score 0):

When you try to request a new access token, use this scope `[https://graph.microsoft.com/.default](https://graph.microsoft.com/.default)`

> All Client Credentials requests on the v2 endpoint must include `scope={resource}/.default` where `{resource}` is the API which the app intends to call.

References: [c# - AADSTS70011: The provided value for the input parameter 'scope' is not valid - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51781898/aadsts70011-the-provided-value-for-the-input-parameter-scope-is-not-valid), [Application permission 'scopes' · Issue #36432 · MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs · GitHub](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/issues/36432#issuecomment-546324396) and [Cannot get access token for scope https://graph.microsoft.com/User.ReadWrite.All · Issue #449 · AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-dotnet · GitHub](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-dotnet/issues/449)